# Struggling to 'fix' normals

Tags: normals, bevel

This is a really simple model, I can't get the bevel op to smooth the edges because the normals are wrong.

Normally(!), calculate outside fixes all this, or is this a bug in 2.82?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object has a scale transform, originally it was created from a slab, made from a scaled default cube. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply All Transforms* fixed the normals.

Answer (score 2):

- Recalculate Outside (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>) is **Face Normal orientation**.
- What you have marked on screen is **Vertex Normal Direction**.

Try search for Normal Average.
For more info read [Blenders Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/normals.html) bottom part.

Comment: Thanks - but I've tried that, still got those weird normals....